# Transit twice through Malaysia, do I need a second visa for the return flight?

Tags: visas, transit, multiple-entry

Aloha Travelers!
As a general rule, if you are going A-C via a country B, which requires a transit visa in advance, should I get another visa if my return also happen to be C->B->A ?

I am planning to visit a lesser known country, and the point B country requires a visa in advance. There is an embassy in our country and it's easier to get a visit visa. Is it the general practice to get 2 transit visas, or is there such "multiple-entry transit visa" thing?

One transit visa allows me to stay 5 days in the country, and provide the departure ticket. The point C country also has an embassy of country B there, and I will be saying 20 days in the country C.

Please note I'm asking the general rules, and not the specifics. That is not just for a singe trip. The point B is a hub for most flights so I'm looking for potential future trips and to know the general rules about this.

**Update 1:** the point B country is Malaysia. 
Their rules are somewhat strange that they do have a transit visa on arrival, but that is only if the destination country is in a a few selected array of countries, which my third country is not in.

**Update 2:**
I could ask an official representative at the KLIA2 airport the same question. Note that this is relevant only to citizens of countries that Malaysia is not offering visa on arrival or visa-free entry. Unfortunately, Sri Lanka is being one of them. 
See the information on [this page](http://www.kln.gov.my/web/che_berne/other_information/-/asset_publisher/2TQe/content/transit-without-visa-for-citizens-of-indian-sub-continental-countries?redirect=%2Fweb%2Fche_berne%2Fother_information).
If you are visiting any country listed under #2, you can pass the immigration control and visit the country. However, on your return flight, you cannot do this if your destination (home) country is not in the list. 
After checking flight routes and times of Malaysia Airlines and AirAsiaX, it seems they work nicely with the rules as well. While I'm not 100% sure about this, all of the flights have 2-5 hours of time in between flights which practically makes you stay in the airport.

Comment: There are no general rules, only specifics. Which country are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but you can also post an answer yourself instead of updating your question if you found a (partial) solution to your problem ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Visas are specific to both the country you are visiting and the country you hail from (nationality). When determining if you need to get a visa in advance you should always check two pages:

1: your own countries department of immigration and tourism page. Often there is useful information on these pages for residents/citizens and depending on the country they may provide you with specific immigration information relating to the country you wish to visit.

2: The country you are visiting's immigration page. Here you can certainly look up the visa requirements for your specific nationality and it should tell you specifically what is required of you.

My own personal experience with Malaysian immigration was excellent. They allow for visa on arrival (I'm Australian) for many countries and depending on how quickly you depart/return you may be able to use the same multi-entry tourist visa or just imply get another one.

Below is a list of the countries that can get a visa upon entry, please note that if your country is not on this list you will have to get a visa in your homeland prior to departure. Also, this list is subject to change as per Malaysian governmental regulations.
The full list of countries that have exemptions is as follows:

Those who are exempt from requiring a visa will receive a 90 day permit to stay include:

```
Australia
UK [The United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland]
USA
Canada
France
Germany
Ireland [Eire]
Japan
Lebanon
New Zealand
South Africa
Spain
Sweden
Norway
UAE
Saudi Arabia
Yemen
```

Those who are exempt from requiring a visa will receive a 30 day permit to stay include:

```
Singapore
Thailand
Malta
Portugal
Cyprus
Greece
Slovenia
Philippines
Russia
Switzerland
Netherlands / Holland
Kenya
```

Those who are exempt from requiring a visa will receive a 14 day permit to stay include:

```
Macau
Palestine
Libya 
Iraq
those from Iran will receive a 15 day permit
```

Finally I do not know the conditions but as of January 2014 citizens of India are also able to obtain a visa on arrival.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed answer. I did a visit to Malaysia last week, and asked an immigrant officer the same question. As you said, they have Visa on arrival and transit w/o visa option for a selection of countries. However, unlike the USA, I can stay in the terminal w/o visa for a short time.

Comment: @AyeshK I am not sure I understand how this answer addresses your question. If that's what you were looking for, you might want to update your question because right now accepting this answer is really confusing.

Comment: @AyeshK I understand but the point of accepting an answer (or not) is to be able to sort out questions that still need expertise from questions where readers can find a solution to their problem. Right now, if someone that knows Malaysian regulations well enough to provide a good answer would check the site, they might think this question is already answered and does not need any attention. Conversely, someone in your situation, would open the question hoping to find a solution and be disappointed.

Comment: Point taken, @Relaxed. Travel.SE is extremely helpful no matter what problem I have in my just-began travel life, so I'm trying my best to appreciate them as much possible. I withdrew my action. For the future visitors with same question, see my update 2.

Comment: @Akesh you need to make your question clearer as this is the most up to date information about visas from Malaysia available. If you were asking if you could stay in the airport then that is a Yes for all airports worldwide as they are considered international land and you need neither visa nor citizenship to reside there. Take this guy for instance, who lived at charles de gaul for 8 years because he had no documents to be able to go anywhere. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehran_Karimi_Nasseri